# Can't run PHP website with Laragon because of "This site can’t provide a secure connection localhost sent an invalid response." error

Tags: php, google-chrome, localhost, laragon

When I try to run a PHP website with Laragon I get `This site can’t provide a secure connection localhost sent an invalid response. Try running Windows Network Diagnostics. ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR`

I already changed the hostname template within Laragon to {name}.local and {name}.mc but didn't worked.
What should I do? (Other PHP built  websites are still working)

Answer (score 5):

I right clicked on Apache in Laragon, turned SSL on and now it works.

Comment: Omg THANK you! I've been trying to get this simple static site to load for the last 30 minutes, I was starting to think I was taking crazy pills!